# Postgres query dramatically slowing production

Tags: postgresql

**Second issue - productivity*4.
There are two tables `test.purchase` and `test.stock`.  After filling `test.purchase` with `INSERT` query and 4 triggers which are calculate values in this table.

```
INSERT INTO test.purchase(
import_id, product_id, euro_price, qty, expiry_date)
VALUES (2,125,16,27,'2021-03-03');
```

Everything calculated and inserted all values well, but each new query executed much slowly than previous, for example, this query for the row #87 was executed in more than two minutes:

```
Query returned successfully in 2 min 22 secs.
```

Delay progressed so fast that looks like if it will be query for the row #1000, it will be executed tomorrow (((.
Please advise.

```
CREATE TABLE test.purchase
(
import_id integer,
product_id integer,
usd_price numeric(10,2),
euro_price numeric(10,2),
qty integer,
euro_stock_price numeric(10,2),
expiry_date date,
euro_stock_amt numeric(10,2),
CONSTRAINT purchase_product_id_import_id_key UNIQUE (product_id, import_id),
CONSTRAINT purchase_import_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (import_id)
    REFERENCES test.imports (import_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT purchase_product_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES test.products (product_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER "0_tr_purchase_convert_price_to_euro"
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF usd_price
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_convert_price_to_euro();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_convert_price_to_euro()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET euro_price = usd_price / i.rate
FROM test.imports i
WHERE pr.import_id = i.import_id
AND pr.usd_price IS NOT NULL;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER "1_tr_purchase_euro_stock_price"
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF euro_price
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_euro_stock_price();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_euro_stock_price()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET euro_stock_price = euro_price + euro_price * i.costs_per_euro
FROM test.imports i
WHERE pr.import_id = i.import_id;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER "2_tr_purchase_euro_stock_amt"
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF qty, euro_stock_price
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_euro_stock_amt();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_stock_amount_in()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE test.stock s
SET
amount_in = euro_stock_amt
FROM test.purchase pr
WHERE
pr.import_id = s.import_id
AND 
pr.product_id = s.product_id
;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER "3_tr_purchase_stock_plus_new"
AFTER INSERT
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_stock_plus_new();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_stock_plus_new()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test.stock(
product_id,
import_id,
expiry_date,
stock_in
)
VALUES(
NEW.product_id,
NEW.import_id,
NEW.expiry_date,
NEW.qty 
);
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER "4_tr_purchase_stock_amount_in"
AFTER INSERT
ON test.purchase
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_purchase_stock_amount_in();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_purchase_stock_amount_in()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE test.stock s
SET
amount_in = euro_stock_amt
FROM test.purchase pr
WHERE
pr.import_id = s.import_id
AND 
pr.product_id = s.product_id
;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

```
CREATE TABLE test.stock
(
product_id integer,
import_id integer,
expiry_date date,
stock_in integer,
stock_out integer,
stock_balance integer,
amount_in numeric(10,2),
amount_sold numeric(10,2),
amount_balance numeric(10,2),
CONSTRAINT stock_product_id_import_id_key UNIQUE (product_id, import_id),
CONSTRAINT stock_import_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (import_id)
    REFERENCES test.imports (import_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT stock_product_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES test.products (product_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT stock_nonnegative CHECK (stock_balance >= 0)
);
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_stock_balance_update
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF stock_out
ON test.stock
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.fn_stock_balance_update();

CREATE FUNCTION test.fn_stock_balance_update()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE
  test.stock s
SET
  stock_balance = stock_in - stock_out,
  amount_balance = amount_sold - amount_in
WHERE
  NEW.product_id = s.product_id
  AND
  NEW.expiry_date = s.expiry_date;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS)
UPDATE test.stock s
SET
amount_in = euro_stock_amt
FROM test.purchase pr
WHERE
pr.import_id = s.import_id
AND 
pr.product_id = s.product_id
;
```

```
 Update on stock s  (cost=18.18..1951.72 rows=45 width=54) (actual time=1.781..1.782 rows=0 loops=1).  
 Buffers: shared hit=540
 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=18.18..1951.72 rows=45 width=54) (actual time=0.051..1.108 rows=88 loops=1)
     Buffers: shared hit=354
     ->  Seq Scan on stock s  (cost=0.00..2.88 rows=88 width=42) (actual time=0.015..0.118 rows=88 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=2
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on purchase pr  (cost=18.18..22.19 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=88)
           Recheck Cond: ((product_id = s.product_id) AND (import_id = s.import_id))
           Heap Blocks: exact=88
           Buffers: shared hit=352
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on purchase_product_id_import_id_key  (cost=0.00..18.18 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0004..0.004 rows=1 loops=88)
                 Index Cond: ((product_id = s.product_id) AND (import_id = s.import_id))
                 Buffers: shared hit=264
 Planning Time: 0.751 ms
 Execution Time: 1.914 ms
 (15 rows)
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS)
INSERT INTO test.stock(
product_id,
import_id,
expiry_date,
stock_in
)
VALUES
(
NEW.product_id,
NEW.import_id,
NEW.expiry_date,
NEW.qty 
);
```

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"
LINE 10: NEW.product_id,
```

It's very strange result because it's direct insert from one table another and it works well

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS)
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET euro_stock_price = euro_price + euro_price * i.costs_per_euro
FROM test.imports i
WHERE pr.import_id = i.import_id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
```

```
Update on purchase pr  (cost=2.07..139.16 rows=88 width=60) (actual time=1.128..1.129 rows=0 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=627
->  Hash Join  (cost=2.07..139.16 rows=88 width=60) (actual time=0.179..0.469 rows=88 loops=1)
     Hash Cond: (pr.import_id = i.import_id)
     Buffers: shared hit=140
     ->  Seq Scan on purchase pr  (cost=0.00..135.88 rows=88 width=38) (actual time=0.117..0.199 rows=88 loops=1)
           Buffers: shared hit=135
     ->  Hash  (cost=2.03..2.03 rows=3 width=14) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=3 loops=1)
           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
           Buffers: shared hit=2
           ->  Seq Scan on imports i  (cost=0.00..2.03 rows=3 width=14) (actual time=0.004..0.013 rows=3 loops=1)
                 Buffers: shared hit=2
 Time: 0.303 ms
 Trigger 2_tr_purchase_euro_stock_amt: time=319.528 calls=88
 Execution Time: 320.858 ms
 (15 rows)
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS)
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET euro_stock_amt = euro_stock_price * qty
;
```

```
Update on purchase pr  (cost=0.00..69.54 rows=88 width=54) (actual time=0.684..0.684 rows=0 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=535 dirtied=61
->  Seq Scan on purchase pr  (cost=0.00..69.54 rows=88 width=54) (actual time=0.059..0.164 rows=88 loops=1)
     Buffers: shared hit=68
Planning Time: 0.140 ms
Execution Time: 0.734 ms
(6 rows)
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,BUFFERS,SETTINGS)
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET euro_price = usd_price / i.rate
FROM test.imports i
WHERE pr.import_id = i.import_id
AND pr.usd_price IS NOT NULL;
```

```
 Update on purchase pr  (cost=2.07..71.28 rows=29 width=61) (actual time=0.448..0.449 rows=0 loops=1)
 Buffers: shared hit=130 dirtied=3
 ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.07..71.28 rows=29 width=61) (actual time=0.047..0.258 rows=29 loops=1)
     Hash Cond: (pr.import_id = i.import_id)
     Buffers: shared hit=70
     ->  Seq Scan on purchase pr  (cost=0.00..68.88 rows=29 width=39) (actual time=0.012..0.138 rows=29 loops=1)
           Filter: (usd_price IS NOT NULL)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 59
           Buffers: shared hit=68
     ->  Hash  (cost=2.03..2.03 rows=3 width=17) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=3 loops=1)
           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
           Buffers: shared hit=2
           ->  Seq Scan on imports i  (cost=0.00..2.03 rows=3 width=17) (actual time=0.004..0.009 rows=3 loops=1)
                 Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning Time: 0.447 ms
Trigger 1_tr_purchase_euro_stock_price: time=148624.503 calls=29
Execution Time: 148625.095 ms
(17 rows)
```

Looks like `fn_purchase_convert_price_to_euro` is the source of slowing, so I need to re-write it.

Thanks to everybody for advises )

Comment: Read this [Slow Queries](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) and then get back with information mentioned.

Comment: `beautylabs=# SET track_io_timing = on;   
SET.   
beautylabs=# explain(analyse, buffers) select * from test.purchase;
                                               QUERY PLAN

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------
 Seq Scan on purchase  (cost=0.00..2000.87 rows=87 width=38) (actual time=3.820.
.3.901 rows=87 loops=1)
 Buffers: shared hit=2000
 Planning Time: 0.244 ms
 Execution Time: 4.020 ms
(4 rows)`

Comment: you should run `explain (analyze)` for the slow **INSERT** statement - that will include the runtime for each of those triggers. And please **[edit]** your question and add the plan to it. Do not put code or additional information into comments

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some doubts about the logic in the triggers. This is just one example of an update, that is not needed (I think):

```
UPDATE test.purchase pr
SET euro_price = usd_price / i.rate
FROM test.imports i
WHERE pr.import_id = i.import_id
AND pr.usd_price IS NOT NULL;
```

This one fires after the INSERT, see trigger 0_tr_purchase_convert_price_to_euro. You first INSERT the data, then the TRIGGER fires and it updates the record you just inserted. Why? I would have created the euro_price before the INSERT and then INSERT the correct value. And there wouldn't be a need for an UPDATE.

The other functions that do updates, have the same issues.

Comment: It doesn't help? Your update takes 148625.095 ms and you can drop this one already.  Without this unnecessary update, your INSERT query must be faster, at least 148 seconds. DROP these triggers, there is no need for

Comment: I make new trigger BEFORE INSERT but it doesn't help in this case (((  main problem in my case is, if I insert price in USD it works perfect converting it in EUR, but if I put EURO price with direct INSERT, like in this statement, function endless try to find value in usd_price cell which is NULL... for this reason I add to `fn_purchase_convert_price_to_euro' option `pr.usd_price IS NOT NULL' but as I see it's slowing this query dramatically. Suppose it has to be function with `IF... ELSE`

Comment: Why do try to find a value in USD when usd_price is NULL? That's doesn't make sense. You have to fix your logic. And you can drop all triggers & trigger functions that do an update on the same table on the same records.

Comment: Logic is very simple... if we have invoice nominated in usd, we have to convert all prices to euro and rest of calculations will go as it written ( at least for today) ... for prices already nominated in euro, they goes directly to calculations... but it doesn't work if we don't put condition `pr.usd_price IS NOT NULL' ... if you have any suggestion, please advise